# Java. First loop doesnt work

Tags: java

i got a little problem with my code. When i write "exit" still shows statement "Unknown command" and i want to show "Bye". Can you help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner odczyt = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word;

        do{
            word = odczyt.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Unknown command");
        }
        while(word!="exit");
            System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Unknown command" will always be printed. Besides that you shouldn't use `=` to compare `Strings`. You should use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Comment: I change while to `while("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(word))` now only when i write "exit" shows "Unknown commend"

Comment: You want `while(!"exit".equalsIgnoreCase(word))` don't forget the negation `!`...

Comment: Thanks a lot @brso05! ;) It works :)

Comment: @Ernest You're welcome!